# Materialized view log creation

Tags: oracle

I have a materialized view on a table on remote DB using DB link.

The below query works and able to view the result.

```
select * from  dept_owner.department@dept_link;
```

But getting error while trying to create a materialized view.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "ORADBA"."department" ("DEPT_NUM", "DEPT_NAME")
  REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT (trunc(sysdate + 1) + 5/24)
  AS select DEPT_NUM,DEPT_NAME from  dept_owner.department@dept_link;
```

Error,

> ORA-23413: table "dept_owner"."department" does not have a
> materialized view log
> 23413. 00000 -  "table "%s"."%s" does not have a materialized view log"
> *Cause:    The fast refresh can not be performed because the master table
> does not contain a materialized view log.
> *Action:   Use the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG command to create a
> materialized view log on the master table.

I created VIEW LOG in my DB for this view, but still getting the above error.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "ORADBA"."DEPARTMENT" WITH ROWID EXCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

I have the same materialized view on another environment with the same DB link and it works. Not sure what is missing here.

**Questions:-**

I have this materialized view on both the Dev DB and IT DB. IT DB materialized view is working for long time. Running into issue when creating the materialized view in Dev DB.

Do we need to create a VIEW LOG on the remote DB link DB and give grants for users from both Dev and IT DB?
Do we need to create VIEW LOG in Dev and IT DB?

Comment: What do you mean by "I created VIEW LOG in my DB for this view".  You need to run 'create materialized view log on dept_owner.department' in the database where that table resides

Comment: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "ORADBA"."DEPARTMENT"
WITH ROWID EXCLUDING NEW VALUES;

Comment: @user1578872, If you or I aware of the usage of `MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG` then we should agree to the point as  @Connor McDonald mentioned. 2. If you say `I have the same materialized view on another environment with the same DB link and it works` then why do you need to create materialized view log again ? 3. If I assume by myself and imagine its working somewhere then you could look into the grants for materialized view log where it works vs where it doesn't.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, I have DB for Dev env and IT env. These 2 DBs are using DB link with some other application DB. The materialized view on IT DB is working, but the same materialized view on Dev is not working. Is that clear for you?

Comment: As i said if its working in one why even you aare trying to creating materialized view log in this case ? Can you clarify this point ?

Comment: As i said, I need this for each env. I can not point my application to point cross DB just for materialized view and I think its a bad practice.

Comment: You probably got me wrong. My question is you have a db link somewhere and now you want to use it  `Dev env` and `IT env`. As you said it is working in `IT env`, does it mean you have created the log same way in `IT Dev` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223129/discussion-between-user1578872-and-sujitmohanty30).